# set auth header in rails link_to path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have to add auth header to the request. I tried adding:

```
:headers => $auth_headers
```

In the method:

```
link_to("Verify", agency_verify_path(agency), :method => :put, :headers => $auth_headers)
```

But token authentication failed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set headers in a `link_to`.

Create a controller action that sets the proper headers and redirects the user to your destination.

Also, prefer `auth_headers` or `@auth_headers` over `$auth_headers`.

Answer (score 0):

According this guide https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#rails-ujs-event-handlers

You may use `ajax:beforeSend` event.

```rb
  link_to("Verify", agency_verify_path(agency), method: :put, remote: true, class: "foo")
```

```js
 $('.foo').bind('ajax:beforeSend', function(xhr, opts) {
   opts.setRequestHeader("x-foo", "foo");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that

```
<%= link_to "Process to survey", send("api_v1_survey_url", Hash[@scope_name, {email: @resource.email, token: @token}]) %>
```